# laravel Change Database connection run time

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to change laravel 5 database connection in run time.

Do you have any idea about it?

Please share with me.

Thanks.

Comment: This link will help http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update**: This answer is from 2015! I haven't used Laravel in years and I am not up to date with the latest best practices. This answer keeps getting upvoted so I suppose it works but please proceed with caution.

---

Well, my immediate answer to this is: **don't.** Chances are that you can accomplish your task by changing your data model and working with some more advanced relationships. It's hard to tell without knowing what you want to do but it seems to me like a bad idea in general, specially if you're planning on using eloquent models and so on

That said, in some scenario where you really need to alter data in another database or execute some raw query you can use the `DB::connection()` method. Something like:

```
$data = DB::connection('another_connection')->select(...);
```

You can specify that `another_connection` variable at your `database.php` file. Like this:

```
<?php
return array(

'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(

    # Your regular connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'password'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',

    ),

    # Your new connection
    'another_connection' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'another_host',
        'database'  => 'another_db',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'password1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
    ),
),
);
```

You can even specify a connection for each eloquent model using `protected $connection = 'another_connection';` also you can specify a connection for each model instance created/queried at run time

```
$user = new User;
$user->setConnection('another_connection');
$user1 = $user->find(1);
```

But then again, I personally don't think this is a good idea and it seems to me that everything can get messy and fall apart very quickly as your application grows in complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried changing the `connection` property in the Model's method, but using the `connection` method on the DB facade did the trick. To elaborate a valid use case: I'm creating small system that checks if all data is correctly mapped. This requirement introduced itself when I was experiencing free text entrances opportunaties for users and myself on the reporting end. All application data is stored in a MySQL database but I need to query the SQL server in order to validate if my - in MySQL - saved queries run into trouble on the production end.

Comment: Personally, I am against switching connections. And I am not getting the idea of validating data after storing it, data should be validated before storage.

Comment: Thanks, just for the record, Not only `DB` but also `Schema` has a connection function, it works like so: `Schema::connection('pgsql_admin')->create(`

Comment: actually, it's very good idea to changing connections in runtime if you're using multiple databases and did unit/function test well.

Answer (score 36):

You can change the connection details during run time using

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'other_database');
```

but don't forget to run `purge` before in order to delete the cache

```
DB::purge('mysql');
```

Comment: I wasted ten hours trying to change de default database at runtime. What I forgot was the DB::purge() method. Thank you!

Comment: Really thanks for help. DB::purge('mysql') is the key!

Comment: If the other database uses another password, you'll need `Config::set('database.connections.mysql', Config::get('database.connections.other_database'));` where "other_database" is its own key pointing to an array of credentials

Answer (score 6):

You can change it like this since Laravel 5.x or 6.x

```
config(['database.default' => 'databasename']);
```

Where `databasename` has to be specified in `config/database` in the `connections` array.

Comment: This is the way to do it. The database conection needs to be defined. It seems that JUST changing the database name for the 'mysql' connection doesn't always work

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar scenario, where to look for historic data, we change the database. We use the following in the model:

```
public function inventory($db, $id) {
  return DB::table($db . '.inventory')->where('inventoryid', $id)->get();
}
```

and then, on the code, we send the $db as a parameter:

```
$inventory = Inventory::inventory('data_2016', 2);
```

This way, you don't need to define the connection for each of the different databases and don't tinker with the database config files.

The only downside is that you are unable to use the model directly, instead you have to use the DB helper.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure another connection at runtime (tested on Laravel 9)

```php
$runtimeConnectionConfig = array_merge(config('database.connections.mysql'), [
    'host' => 'db_host',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'user' => 'db_user',
    'password' => 'db_pass',
]);

config(['database.connections.NEW_CONNECTION_NAME' => $runtimeConnectionConfig]);

$runtimeConnection = DB::connection('NEW_CONNECTION_NAME');

$data = $runtimeConnection->table('users')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have mysql and sqlsrv configuration into config/database.php file.
Mysql database is my default connection, and I put this into a controller to get some info about studets data and try to update mysql info:

```
$data = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select("select * From students");
```

And gets me this error:

```
could not find driver
SELECT * FROM students
```

I am using laravel 10, I do not have any Model created, that is why I do not use Eloquent.
So I do not have any advance about this point.  Somebody can help.
Thnks

Comment: I need to say that I resolve this problem:  I did not have installed PHP libraries for SQL-Server  into my PHP.ini and into my "ext" folder.  Already is working properly.