# Laravel: how to copy data from one connection to one other?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've a `mysql` connection and a `pgsql` (postgres, set as default) connection.

I must read all rows from a table from mysql and then save all into postgres

I tried do this, remembering that my default connection is `pgsql`

```
$mysql_model = new Regioni();
$regioni = $mysql_model->setConnection("mysql")->all();
```

But it's still using `pgsql` connection.

I'm sure of this because i tried to insert a row into pgsql table, (it was empty), and I can dump this single row as results of all.

Also, I (only for debugging, do not hate me), modified `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`, adding a debug echo into this method

```
/**
 * Set the connection associated with the model.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $name
 * @return $this
 */
public function setConnection($name)
{
    echo "Model calling setConnection($name)" . PHP_EOL;
    $this->connection = $name;

    return $this;
}
```

As a result I can see

```
Model calling setConnection(mysql)
Model calling setConnection()
Model calling setConnection(pgsql)
```

The first one is the result of my explicit setConnection.

But why calling `->all()` will reset connection to default one?

### Main goal/question

What's the right way to dinamically change the connection of a model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel Change Database connection run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041893/laravel-change-database-connection-run-time). Besides that, it appears to me that data migration might be done via raw DB queries instead for better control, or standalone tools, specifically built for it.

Comment: I cannot. And the change db suggested my a solution that I write right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my actual solution.
It's ugly, but it works.

The requisite for this is that default connection is `pgsql` so I must set connection explicitly to read all table record from `nysql`

Aftert that, I loop throught and then save to `pgsql` simply doing an insert at time

```
    $regioni =  (new Regioni)->setConnection('mysql')->get();
    (new Regioni)->truncate();
    foreach($regioni as $r) {
        (new Regioni)->insert($r->toArray());
    }
```

Note that this is specifically for my case

- I have an old mysql to be migrated to the new postgresql
- I already did migrations on postgresql so all structures are ready
- I read all data from source and simply write into target postgres
- this must be done only one time
- I truncate target before insert (to be repeatable in development)

If you can suggest something more efficient, please, write an answer