# Laravel - How to load updated database connection information from .env file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am trying to write an installer-type app using Laravel 10. Where the purpose is: if I don't set the database information it will redirect me to the setup database. When I fill up the form and submit, it performs the following task:

1. Update database-related content in the .env file
2. Clear cache, config, and finally cache new config using the `Artisan` call.
3. Finally migrate the database still using the `Artisan` call.

Although the `.env` file content is updated, it still uses the last database-related info that existed before the update. I mean, suppose previously DB name was `ab_setup`, then I update it to `nn_setup`, `.env` file shows the DB name as `nn_setup`, but the browser responds:

> Unknown database `ab_setup` (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = nn_setup and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE').

I have no idea what's actually wrong. Here is my code:

```
// Update .env file content
$envContent = [
    'DB_CONNECTION' =>  $request->database_connection,
    'DB_HOST'       =>  $request->database_host,
    'DB_PORT'       =>  $request->database_port,
    'DB_DATABASE'   =>  $request->database_name,
    'DB_USERNAME'   =>  $request->database_username,
    'DB_PASSWORD'   =>  $request->database_password
];

foreach( $envContent as $key => $value ) {
    $this->replace_env_value($key, $value);
}

// Clear Cache and Config & Cache new Config
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
Artisan::call('config:clear');
Artisan::call('config:cache');

// Migrate DB and Seed
Artisan::call('migrate');
Artisan::call('db:seed');

// Create Admin User
$user = new User();
$user->name = $request->admin_name;
$user->email = $request->admin_username;
$user->password = Hash::make($request->admin_password);
$user->save();
```

Does anyone have the idea what I miss that will fix the issue?

Comment: `.env` values are passed to Laravel's `config()`, like `config('database')`; I wonder if that is being "sticky", despite the call to `config:clear`  If you do `dd(config('database.connections.' . config('database.default')))` following that artisan call, do you see the old or new values?

Comment: Thanks for your idea, unfortunately, it doesn't update the value in config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reconnect the database manually.
Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682512/21200312).

Also, you need to remove cache before with [DB:purge()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37705096/21200312) method

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now I face another issue. After the operation, the redirection should be `<ROOT_URL>/login` based on this code `return redirect()->route('login');` but unfortunately, it tries to redirect in `localhost/login`

Comment: Did you check APP_URL in the .env file? Also, you can set base url in config/app.php file.
`'url' => 'example.com',`

Comment: I solve this in an alternative way. But there is another issue. After successfully completing the action of the db_installation method, it redirects to the login page. When I tried to log in, interestingly the login page got the old DB configuration.

I mean I performed `DB::disconnect();`, `DB::purge();`, and `Config::set('database.connections.mysql', [all_db_info_set_here]);` which successfully create related tables and insert data in the new record. But when I use `dd(config('database.connections.mysql'));` before redirect to login page, surprisingly it prints old DB info!